# place and size button under text with css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to come around this problem, but I can't find a way to make it work. Therefore I have come here for help.

My idea is that I want to place and size the button under the 99 / 99 text as seen on the image

[Image of the html with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ZvT.png)

My html

```
    <div class="btnAttackUpgrade">
        <button class="btnUpgrade btnAttackSize" onclick="meleeupgPage();totalClick();"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="btnRangedUpgrade">
        <button class="btnUpgrade btnRangedSize" onclick="btnTest2();totalClick();"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="btnSlayerUpgrade">
        <button class="btnUpgrade btnSlayerSize" onclick="btnTest3();totalClick();"></button>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.btnUpgrade {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0 none;
    outline: none;   
}

.btnAttackSize {
    width: 31%;
    height: 9%;
}

.btnRangedSize {
    width: 31%;
    height: 9%;
}

.btnSlayerSize {
    width: 31%;
    height: 9%;
}

div.btnSlayerUpgrade {
    position: relative;
    top: 67%;
    left: 34.5%;
}

div.btnRangedUpgrade {
    position: relative;
    top: 34%;
    left: 1%;
}

div.btnAttackUpgrade{
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5%;
    left: 1%;
}
```

I know if I remove `position: relative;` completely from lets say *btnSlayerUpgrade* it sizes the button as I want, but then it will not stay under the text. It wont be effected by the width and heigth changes. See the picture [After I removed position relative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkUaM.png)

What stop the button from resizing when it has a position to it in css

Answer (score 0):

If  understand your question correctly I think the easiest and most responsive way to do this is to put both elements as siblings in a container with display:flex and with centred children.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btnAttackUpgrade"></div>
    <button class="btnUpgrade btnAttackSize" onclick="meleeupgPage();totalClick();"></button>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    //flex-direction: column; (default)
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.btnAttackUpgrade{
    //unnecessary
}
.btnUpgrade .btnAttackSize{
    //unnecessary 
}
```